# Screen-reader friendly way to label a checkbox / radio button, that is already using a label to be click-able

Tags: html, checkbox, radio-button, screen-readers

If I want a checkbox / radio to be filled when the user clicks the associated text, then I tend to wrap it in a label e.g.

HTML

```
<fieldset class="inline">
      <label for="radio-inline-1" class="block-label">
            <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="radio-inline-group" id="radio-inline-1">
           Yes
     </label>
     <label for="radio-inline-2" class="block-label selected">
          <input type="radio" value="No" name="radio-inline-group" id="radio-inline-2">
           No
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

So... how do I now label the checkbox / radio **set's** question in a compliant manor?

Is it a case of "whatever" html + css? e.g.

HTML

```
<p class="pretendLabel">Do you like compliant code?</p>
<fieldset class="inline">
      <label for="radio-inline-1" class="block-label">
            <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="radio-inline-group" id="radio-inline-1">
           Yes
     </label>
     <label for="radio-inline-2" class="block-label selected">
          <input type="radio" value="No" name="radio-inline-group" id="radio-inline-2">
           No
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

Or do I use an extra label with two "for"s, unwrap the labels or something else?

My concern is mainly around screen readers not correctly associating the question and potential answers without a "for" or other direct association on the pretend label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a fieldset with a legend element.

```
<fieldset class="inline">
    <legend>Do you like compliant code?</legend>
```

Comment: Oh, that is simple! Does the legend associate to the parent fieldset for screen-readers?

Comment: Yes. That is what you were asking for.